# How to add a dynamic URL to tabulator cell?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm making a linked cell in Tabulator. I formatted the cell content as

```
formatterParams: {
            labelField: "id",
            url: "localhost:8080/taskEditor/value,
            target: "_blank",
          },
```

I tried with a function, but the url was not generated correctly. It only gave me localhost:8080/value.
I would like to know how I can program a url as in the code above, where value is replaced by a string id. The value is in fact the value in the cell. How can I get the cell value and turn the text into a hyperlink, clicking on which, the user is able to see more detail of clicked value.
I'm doing this in vue.js environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but try this:
Instead of using the "formatterParams", create the link using the "formatter".

First create a function like the one below:

```
 function link(cell, formatterParams){
    var url = cell.getValue();
    return "<a href='/taskEditor/"+url+"'>"+url+"</a>";
}
```

then generate the column with the code below:

```
{title:"ID", field:"id", formatter:link, hozAlign:"center"},
```

Example here:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9j8nt1b/)

Comment: Hi Alisson, Thanks for the response, it solved my problem.I could have never figured it out.

Comment: Although a separate question, but I'll ask :) I'm able to get the link, it works, clicking on the link opens it on the same page but I don't see the data for that task in question. Whereas, I've another pop-up with a "More" button next to the same task brief and I'm able to view the data. I get a blank page with "server error: Not Found". I'm on vue.js, node.js, express.js setup. Can you help with ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Is better use the html format

`{title:"Acciones", field:"acciones", width:150, formatter:"html"},`

`var tabledata = [ {id:1, acciones:"Oli <b><a href='#?id=12'>Editar</a>  <a href='#?id=12'>Borrar</a></b>", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""}]`